# Adding messaging to cart based on Brand and Ship-to State

Tags: php, magento

I am not very proficient at PHP and I am faced with a situation where if a specific brand is shipping to a specific state a message need to appear at the first stage of checkout. I am working in Theme/app/design/frontend/onecall/default/template/checkout and I have been successful at pulling back the brand, but not the 'region_id'

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to show your code

Comment: At this point all I have is: '<?php
$cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
          ->getQuote()
          ->getAllItems();
    foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
        $brand = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
        echo $ean;
    }
    ?>'

Comment: Try the [magento.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks! I have posted it there as well.